# LINQ to empty Collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have one simple linq in my VM:

```
 public int MaxItem => Collection.Max((c)=> c.Count);
```

There is no problem with it, if `Collection` is full of items. But if I need cleared it like this :

```
Collection.Clear();
```

Then I have Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException

How can fix it ?

Comment: What do you *want* to happen when your collection has no items in it?

Comment: What is the type of your `Collection`?

Comment: @Servy I want --> `MaxItem` = 0.

Comment: @MageXy Collection - is the Custom class. Count - `int` Property

Comment: @Сергей And what problems are you having returning that value when the collection is empty?

Comment: `Collection.Any() ? Collection.Max((c)=> c.Count) : 0;`

Comment: @MattBurland exactly, what I need!

Comment: Never mind I misunderstood your question.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetail just for future questions, the exception details should be included in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Max` (and `Min`) are undefined for empty sets, so the only reasonable behavior is to throw exception when sequence has no items.

If you need special handling for your collection - check for empty (or "full of items") condition and call different methods:

```
   public int MaxItem => Collection.IsFullOfItems ? 
        Collection.Max((c)=> c.Count) : 0;
```

(You can use `Any()` or `Count != 0` for most collection types if you don't have your custom `IsFullOfItems` property)

Alternatively  if `Collection` is your custom class you can implement your own `Max(Func<bool, T> predicate)` method in that class and it will be used in `Collection.Max` call instead of default `Enumerable.Max` extension method.